# Note able to get route params from service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

Okay, I must be doing something wrong. I am trying to get the id from a route in a service.

Let explain, I have a service that i would like to be able to lookup the id from the route where I don't have to do it in the component that is being navigated to as i wanted an interface so that I could easily test things.

The really strange thing is that if I do the exact same thing in the component as the service one returns the id the other returns undefined.

```
this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(params=> console.log(params));
```

Answer (score 0):

> The really strange thing is that if I do the exact same thing in the component as the service one returns the id the other returns undefined.

If you aren't passing the activeRoute into the service method, it won't have access to this data. The service is (usually) a singleton that lives outside the component scope and is injected via the DI system.

**An alternative** would be to have the service method (or static function) accept the active route as a parameter and work with what the component passes in. You could pass it from the component in the ngOnInit.

```
//service or static method
recordParams(activeRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    activeRoute.params.subscribe(params=> console.log(params));
}

//component
constructor(private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute, private theService: TheService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.theService.recordParams(this.activeRoute);
}
```

**More alternatively**, you have have a base type of component that does this in the ngOnInit and any component you want to have this functionality can extend the base, call the parent constructor (passing in the activated route), and call super.ngOnInit.

If you expand a little more on your end goal, I'd be happy to give a more specific answer!